# GnuPG: replace "pinentry" with custom GUI

Tags: gnupg, dialog

I am using GnuPG for my application and sometimes I need to type a pin in order to proceed.

When I do that, I get the following `pinentry` dialog:

[image]

But I would like to change that dialog and put my custom on(the one which I created by using React).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GnuPG interacts with pinentry using a text-based protocol "Assuan IPC". The overall format is exactly the same as that used by gpg-agent, scdaemon, and other GnuPG components.

To implement it, your program needs to be able to receive commands through stdin and receive responses through stdout. The Assuan IPC protocol is entirely text-based with one command per line, and with percent-encoded values (like in URLs, except spaces are *not* converted to +).

The commands used by pinentry are documented in the [`info "(pinentry)Protocol"`](http://info2html.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/info2html-demo/info2html?(pinentry)Protocol) info page. Your program needs to accept commands such as OPTION, SETPROMPT, SETTITLE, SETDESC, etc. and return OK/ERR responses.

```
    */usr/bin/pinentry is started*
Pinentry:   OK Carlos' React-based Pinentry Ready!
GnuPG:      OPTION display=:0
Pinentry:   OK
GnuPG:      SETDESC Please%20unlock%20the%20card
Pinentry:   OK
GnuPG:      GETPIN
    *the GUI window shows up*
    *user enters "secret password"*
Pinentry:   D secret%20password
Pinentry:   OK
```

Once you receive the `GETPIN` or `CONFIRM` command, you can show the appropriate window, and once you have the input you have to return it through stdout as a "data" response ('D' before the 'OK').

Finally, configure `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` to use your custom 'pinentry-program' instead of the standard one.